# How can I run DataNucleus Enhancer from Gradle?

Tags: gradle, datanucleus

Is there a gradle plugin for running DataNucleus Enhancer? As I can see from documentation you can run it only from Maven or Ant: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/enhancer.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I searched and found no plugin for running the DataNucleus Enhancer from Gradle. But there is a way of doing this by using the DataNucleus Enhancer Ant task.

I added the following in my `build.gradle`.

```
task datanucleusEnhance {
    description "Enhance JPA model classes using DataNucleus Enhancer"
    dependsOn compileJava

    doLast {    
        // define the entity classes
        def entityFiles = fileTree(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir).matching {
            include 'com/mycom/*.class', 'org/myorg/*.class'
        }

        println "Enhancing with DataNucleus the following files"
        entityFiles.getFiles().each {
            println it
        }

        // define Ant task for DataNucleus Enhancer
        ant.taskdef(
            name : 'datanucleusenhancer',
            classpath : sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
            classname : 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerTask'
            // the below is for DataNucleus Enhancer 3.1.1
            //classname : 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask'
        )

        // run the DataNucleus Enhancer as an Ant task
        ant.datanucleusenhancer(
            classpath: sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
            verbose: true,
            api: "JPA") {
            entityFiles.addToAntBuilder(ant, 'fileset', FileCollection.AntType.FileSet)
        }
    }
}

classes.dependsOn(datanucleusEnhance)
```

In the `entityFiles` is where you configure your JPA entity annotated classes.

Unfortunately you cannot see the enhancer output, as this task is using Ant logging. Unless you're running gradle with `-i` or `-d` option.

Using: Java 8, `org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0`, `org.datanucleus:datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms:4.1.1`.

Comment: With version 3.1.1 of the DataNucleus Enhancer, the class name for the enhancer task now appears to be `'org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask'`

Comment: How should this task be added to the project & called?

Comment: @Tom, this is a Gradle task, just add it in your build.gradle. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse you should use the Gradle integration.

Comment: @AdrianBer I figured it out in the end; it might be worth pointing out that the script must go _above_ `war.dependsOn datanucleusEnhance` if your build.gradle needs it.

Comment: @Tom, actually I think it is better to have `classes.dependsOn(datanucleusEnhance)`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi Adrian, any way you can update this to show what versions of all of this you used?  Clearly, you're not using 3.1.1, and if you don't get the versions all exactly right between all these things, it refuses to run... Thank you.

Comment: @jmort253, there's a commented line there for v3.1.1

Comment: @AdrianBer Yes, I see that, but I can't get 3.1.1 to work, and at this point don't care what version I use as long as it works. The dependencies needed for each version aren't clearly documented. That's why I was hoping you could show what versions you used for the dependencies if you have a moment to spare.  Clearly, whatever versions you used work for you, and I would like to know what versions that was.  Why didn't you use 3.1.1?  You couldn't get the latest to work either?  Thank you.

Comment: Also, what version of Java were you using?  Java 7 or Java 8? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not working on that project anymore, but back then I was using Java 8 and org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0, org.datanucleus:datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms:4.1.1. I hope this helps. I will state this in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly different approach. First of all I've created `EntityEnhancer` class in my project. This class calls DataNucleus enhancer via its main method. Then I called this class from Gradle's JavaExec task.

This prints out all enhancer's log messages on Gradle console and also can be called from IDE.

EntityEnhancer class uses Spring Boot 1.3.5 library.

```java
public class EntityEnhancer {

    private static final ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider ENTITY_SCANNER;
    static {
        ENTITY_SCANNER = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        ENTITY_SCANNER.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "Expected single argument <package_to_scan>!");
        String pathToScan = args[0];
        String[] classesToEnhance = findEntityClasses(pathToScan);
        Validate.isTrue(classesToEnhance.length > 0, "No classes to enhance has been found!");

        DataNucleusEnhancer enhancer = new DataNucleusEnhancer("JPA", null);
        enhancer.addClasses(classesToEnhance);
        enhancer.enhance();
    }

    private static String[] findEntityClasses(String packageToScan) throws IOException {
        Set<BeanDefinition> entityBeanDefinitions = ENTITY_SCANNER.findCandidateComponents(packageToScan);
        List<String> entityClasses = entityBeanDefinitions.stream().map(BeanDefinition::getBeanClassName).collect(Collectors.toList());
       return entityClasses.toArray(new String[]{});
    }
}
```

Task definition for your `build.gradle` file. This actually puts your just-compiled classes on the classpath and runs `EntityEnhancer` class.

```groovy
// Call this task from your IDE after project compilation.
task enhanceJpaEntities(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.your.project.package.EntityEnhancer'
    args 'com.your.entities.package'
}

classes.doLast {
    enhanceJpaEntities.execute()
}
```

Comment: why not just set the "persistence-unit" to enhance rather than imposing a dependency on Spring just to get classes? https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/enhancer/DataNucleusEnhancer.java#L453

Comment: @NeilStockton Good point. Unfortunately to do this you need to have persistence.xml file on your classpath (which I don't have) or you have to implement DataNucleus PersistenceUnitMetaData class. But if you have I will save some more lines of code.

Comment: hmm, that could easily be put in a Gradle plugin :)

Comment: @Stef That is correct! I've done this as a part of a demo application. My intention was not to create an extra plugin or do anything in Groovy. Just to make it as simple as possible (less code as possible). Source code of demo application is here: https://github.com/vkuzel/Orm-Frameworks-Demo/tree/master/datanucleus