# Using DataNucleus JDO with Gradle and IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, jdo, datanucleus

I'm working on a small REST application server and I'm trying to be able to save a Java bean using DataNucleus JDO with MySQL.

My only problem is that I can't find any examples of any application that uses DataNucleus JDO and is built using Gradle.

I'm new to using Java and I have essentially no idea how to go about doing this. At this moment I'm just considering going with Hibernate JPA instead but I feel like JDO would be better for me in the long run. I would really appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Gradle surely must have ample documentation, and all you are doing with DataNucleus is executing Java processes. A simple search reveals such as https://divinespear.github.io/jpa-schema-gradle-plugin/  which you could easily inspect and use.

Comment: @Neil That example specifically doesn't support datanucleus though. Thank you though, I will try adapting it.

Comment: You mean the thing that says "version 0.2 Support datanucleus" ?

Comment: what happened to your "adapting" ?

Comment: @NeilStockton Oh, sorry I should have come back to fill you in. I followed Adrian's solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279503/how-can-i-run-datanucleus-enhancer-from-gradle) with a minor edit. I modified the task to depend on processResources instead of compileJava and made classes depend on datanucleusEnhance, otherwise it didn't work for me. I would normally tell you the error I got but I couldn't see the enhancer's error output. The solution essentially calls an ant task to enhance the classes instead of using Gradle only. It's not the most elegant but it worked.

Comment: Great, so suggest that you add an ANSWER with your solution in it, for future people who need it

Answer (score 1):

I followed Adrian's solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279503/how-can-i-run-datanucleus-enhancer-from-gradle) with a minor edit: I modified the task to depend on *processResources* instead of compileJava and made *classes* depend on datanucleusEnhance, otherwise it didn't work for me.

I would normally tell you the error I got but I couldn't see the enhancer's error output.

The solution essentially calls an ant task to enhance the classes instead of using Gradle only. It's not the most elegant but it worked.