# Enhancing endpoints in Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0 for App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have received an email from GCP to migrate my project from Cloud Endpoints 1.0 to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0.

I've followed the steps outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating?authuser=0

In my previous build.gradle I had this directive to enhance my endpoints and it worked fine:

```
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
    enhancer {
        version = "v2"
        api="jdo"  // or "jpa"
        enhanceOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

However, after migration and on compile, I get the following error:

> Error:(60, 0) Could not find method enhancer() for arguments [build_2dn4fni12bkrsqgsi25gsx3hh$_run_closure2$_closure7@6b02ee9e] on object of type com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension.

And if I remove the `enhancer` part, I get the following error:

> org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager initialiseFileMetaDataForUse: Found Meta-Data for class [...] but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.

So, what is the equivalent enhancing in the new framework?
(I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the new gradle plugin doesn't have the task `appengineEnhance` which is required to enhance your classes for jpa/jdo.

There's a workaround for this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279504/3190492

It's also worth nothing that the `enhancer {...}` section in the `appengine` block won't be required and that configuration should be done in the script in the link above.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error:

taskdef class org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader

Comment: Had to use `'org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask'`

Comment: Thank you for the tips....it should be stated in Google app engine endpoint framework V2  documents (the same way it should be clearly said that you need to upgrade to android support 26)...The new version is not ready and people should not be pushed to migrate on something uncomplete while losing lot of time...we are used as  lab rat for bug testing

Answer (score 0):

I got this response directly from Google Cloud Support:

> There are some features and tools that are excluded and currently
>   unavailable with the latest version of Endpoints v2. If your
>   application requires any of the below mentioned, you are not
>   recommended to migrate.
>
> - JSON-RPC protocol, which is required for legacy iOS clients
> - Automatic ETags
> - Automatic Kind fields
> - IDE integration
> - fields partial responses
>
> Meanwhile, below are the tools that are currently not supported in
>   v2.0:
>
> - Android Studio support for Cloud Endpoints 1.0
> - Android Studio code validation and quick fixes for Cloud Endpoints 1.0
>
> So, with regards to the 'enhancer' method, have you checked if this is
>   included on the aforementioned features? If so, the only way for you
>   to do is check for an equivalent function or downgrade again to v1.0.

This is not the answer I hoped for, but at least till they officially support these features, we should not migrate to Endpoints Framework v2.0.