# How can we use DataNucleus Enhancer Manually in a Cloud Tools for Eclipse project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, ant, datanucleus

I have been working on trying to configure the DataNucleus enhancer to enhance JDO classes in a Java Google App Engine Gradle project.  So far, I have been unsuccessful. I have tried using Gradle's ant integration to create an enhancer task in Gradle, and I've also tried this directly from Ant.

At this point, I'm now trying to do it manually, hoping that this might give me insight into what I'm doing wrong in Gradle and Ant.

However, the output from Java isn't very helpful either, and I'm hoping someone can tell me how I can get this to enhance my classes or tell me how I can find out what is causing the IllegalArgumentException.

Below is the output trying to enhance the classes.  This command was actually reconstructed from digging through the Gradle logs in debug mode:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -classpath /Users/jem/Documents/internworkspace/GPEHelloWorldGAE/build/classes/java/main:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/9b9783ccb2a323383e6e20e36d368f8997b71967/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3/65fd012581ded67bc20945d85c32b4598c3a9cf1/jsoup-1.8.3.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0/da217367fd25e88df52ba79e47658d4cf928b0d1/commons-collections4-4.0.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine.orm/datanucleus-appengine/2.1.2/c94b27586d50c55ab7dd54ee2174282e6a1e96a6/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.jdo/jdo-api/3.1/f6a3c20cb994b8cea14e7da9e52f780bddc89d47/jdo-api-3.1.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.1.1/e1c53ac9a9a0867da9f4136b8df58173c2d5b170/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.1.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/javax.persistence/2.1.1/d903075c7989102ce74956029ceb6a725209861d/javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.1.3/7d242e12ee2171a092b6ba1da6a03f8872f422d7/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.63/1078044e7123f81e54d13014b53126590e7ad1ae/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.63.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jstl/jstl/1.2/74aca283cd4f4b4f3e425f5820cda58f44409547/jstl-1.2.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/3cd63d075497751784b2fa84be59432f4905bf7c/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/transaction-api/1.1/2ca09f0b36ca7d71b762e14ea2ff09d5eac57558/transaction-api-1.1.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/b141c67d55cc19f14639f091b84e692e2198dc50/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar:/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/4.0/659add6efc75a4715d738e73f07505246edf4d66/asm-4.0.jar org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer -d testdir -v /Users/jem/Documents/internworkspace/GPEHelloWorldGAE/build/classes/java/main/com/example/april/full/SampleJdoClass.class
Apr 13, 2018 12:55:06 PM org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer <init>
INFO: DataNucleus Enhancer for API "JDO"
Apr 13, 2018 12:55:06 PM org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer main
INFO: DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.ASMClassEnhancer.getClassNameForFileName(ASMClassEnhancer.java:272)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:727)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
```

Here is the contents of my ant build file:

```
    <project name="ant-enhancer-wrapper" default="" basedir=".">
        <description>

        </description>

            <!-- set global properties for this build -->
            <property environment="env" />
            <property name="gradle.lib" location="${user.home}/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1" />
            <property name="enhancer.classpath" location="${gradle.lib}" />
            <property name="jdo.file.dir" location="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/b141c67d55cc19f14639f091b84e692e2198dc50" />
            <property name="module.classes.dir" location="${basedir}/build/classes/*" />


        <path id="module.lib.classpath">
            <pathelement path="${gradle.lib}/"/>
        </path>

        <path id="enhancer.classpath">
            <!-- <pathelement location="${module.classes.dir}"/> -->
            <!-- <fileset dir="${gradle.lib}" includes="datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar" /> -->
            <fileset dir="${gradle.lib}">
                <include name="**/datanucleus-core-3.1.1.jar" />
                <include name="**/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <!-- <path refid="module.lib.classpath"/> -->
        </path>

        <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${gradle.lib}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="${build}" />
        </path>


            <!-- <target name="datanucleusenhance" depends=""
                description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes.">
                <enhance_war war="src/main/webapp">
                        <args>
                        <arg value="-enhancerVersion"/>
                        <arg value="v2"/>
                    </args>
                </enhance_war>
            </target> -->

            <target name="datanucleusenhance" description="DataNucleus enhancement">
                <echo>$${enhancer.classpath}=${enhancer.classpath}</echo>
                <echo>$${classpath}=${classpath}</echo>
                <echo>$${module.lib.classpath}=${module.lib.classpath}</echo>
                <taskdef name="datanucleusenhancer" classpathref="enhancer.classpath" classname="org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask" />
                <datanucleusenhancer classpathref="enhancer.classpath" failonerror="true" verbose="true">
                    <jvmarg line="-Dlog4j.configuration=${log4j.config.file}"/>
                </datanucleusenhancer>
            </target>

    </project>
```

Since this is a Gradle project, the classfiles are in `build/classes/**`, and of course, all of the project's JAR files are in `~/.gradle/caches/**`

Here is the contents of the classpath in the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.standard.runtimeClasspathProvider/App Engine Standard Runtime" exported="true">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry output="bin/main" kind="src" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/ff7d164b8b09beeb2676661a5ecdfea47e9325b8/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/9b9783ccb2a323383e6e20e36d368f8997b71967/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3/17b6b6cb133d73e13e2e1f3550f90d4e23451b10/jsoup-1.8.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3/65fd012581ded67bc20945d85c32b4598c3a9cf1/jsoup-1.8.3.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0/f8262a0e305c01bb4e8cb4053374315a8bc08e21/commons-collections4-4.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0/da217367fd25e88df52ba79e47658d4cf928b0d1/commons-collections4-4.0.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine.orm/datanucleus-appengine/2.1.2/cff3ed955bc57fea6762019509369c10fedd947f/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine.orm/datanucleus-appengine/2.1.2/c94b27586d50c55ab7dd54ee2174282e6a1e96a6/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.jdo/jdo-api/3.1/b6c42ed0d2c2a796edcd002dfa35486c4b1207be/jdo-api-3.1-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.jdo/jdo-api/3.1/f6a3c20cb994b8cea14e7da9e52f780bddc89d47/jdo-api-3.1.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.1.3/5e9f664ee5a15b59d0c39237298a4ea1742f6dd3/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.1.3/2b516725909217520c9c55b591b5e48ab3a0dc64/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/a00123f261762a7c5e0ec916a2c7c8298d29c400/javax.inject-1-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/2773a7910e8f0c7d59749dc4fcef2a4b94fcf85a/persistence-api-1.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/5725f57873e05e068803e2bf9d5a8ea3740ffec5/persistence-api-1.0.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.1.3/bf9b480345e4ea514c6920732f4e935a202fd444/datanucleus-core-3.1.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.1.3/7d242e12ee2171a092b6ba1da6a03f8872f422d7/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.63/1078044e7123f81e54d13014b53126590e7ad1ae/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.63.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jstl/jstl/1.2/74aca283cd4f4b4f3e425f5820cda58f44409547/jstl-1.2.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/ab3976d4574c48d22dc1abf6a9e8bd0fdf928223/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/3cd63d075497751784b2fa84be59432f4905bf7c/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/transaction-api/1.1/d5dad66d06246bd2e1e369cebff27faa9beb065a/transaction-api-1.1-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/transaction-api/1.1/2ca09f0b36ca7d71b762e14ea2ff09d5eac57558/transaction-api-1.1.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/e212a2f7001d9a28c91b39427ed010cb696ad3e/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/b141c67d55cc19f14639f091b84e692e2198dc50/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/4.0/4a33d6206d6d442446a8edbd2b0798ecfaebc229/asm-4.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/4.0/659add6efc75a4715d738e73f07505246edf4d66/asm-4.0.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.truth/truth/0.33/385d8511e34942bd61861a0a66117270383ac0fa/truth-0.33-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.truth/truth/0.33/66c978542e1c4c0b72508c5e3bd7d36481090171/truth-0.33.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/a6c32b40bf3d76eca54e3c601e5d1470c86fcdfa/junit-4.12-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/8269667b73d9616600359a9b0ba1b1c7d0cf7a97/mockito-all-1.10.19-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/539df70269cc254a58cccc5d8e43286b4a73bf30/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-testing/1.9.63/4ba411d8c319bf47f63793f83b0b29b68fa6f1a/appengine-testing-1.9.63.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-stubs/1.9.63/2ef26c68c6b6ef3f99e8025aac8129764136ddc3/appengine-api-stubs-1.9.63.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.9.63/5513748079aacbbb21baae51dd5206e5a22c8921/appengine-tools-sdk-1.9.63.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/1dc37250fbc78e23a65a67fbbaf71d2e9cbc3c0b/hamcrest-core-1.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/20.0/9c8493c7991464839b612d7547d6c263adf08f75/guava-20.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/20.0/89507701249388e1ed5ddcf8c41f4ce1be7831ef/guava-20.0.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.12/90cff054bd2754d6597cbd7f0e4ac1ab3e381f20/error_prone_annotations-2.0.12-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/jem/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.12/8530d22d4ae8419e799d5a5234e0d2c0dcf15d4b/error_prone_annotations-2.0.12.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
</classpath>
```

I'm not sure if it's helpful, but here is the build.gradle file I'm using. The enhancer task I created is showing the same exception as running manually.

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'    // latest App Engine Gradle tasks
  }
}

plugins {
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.3"
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  /*maven {
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT repository (if needed)
  }*/
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

ext {
    jdoVersion = "3.1"
    dataNucleusVersion = "3.1.3"
}

logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.INFO

dependencies {
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl
  compile group: 'org.apache.taglibs', name: 'taglibs-standard-impl', version: '1.2.5'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
  compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.8.3'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.0'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jdo/jdo-api
  compile group: 'javax.jdo', name: 'jdo-api', version: '3.1'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo
  compile group: 'org.datanucleus', name: 'datanucleus-api-jdo', version: '3.1.3'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer
  compile group: 'org.datanucleus', name: 'datanucleus-enhancer', version: '3.1.1'

  compile('javax.inject:javax.inject:1')

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.orm/datanucleus-appengine
  compile group: 'com.google.appengine.orm', name: 'datanucleus-appengine', version: '2.1.2'


  compile('javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0')

  //compile('org.datanucleus:javax.persistence:2.1.1')
  compile('org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3')
  //compile('org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:5.0.2')
  //compile('org.datanucleus:datanucleus-rdbms:5.0.2')


  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:+'  // Latest App Engine Api's
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

  compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'

// Add your dependencies here.
//  compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud:+'   // Latest Cloud API's http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'com.google.truth:truth:0.33'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'

  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:+'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:+'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:+'
}

// Always run unit tests
appengineDeploy.dependsOn test
appengineStage.dependsOn test

appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
  deploy {   // deploy configuration

  }
  run {
    jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005']
  }
  run {
    jvmFlags = ["-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=1"]
  }
}

test {
  useJUnit()
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
  beforeTest { descriptor ->
     logger.lifecycle("test: " + descriptor + "  Running")
  }

  onOutput { descriptor, event ->
     logger.lifecycle("test: " + descriptor + ": " + event.message )
  }
  afterTest { descriptor, result ->
    logger.lifecycle("test: " + descriptor + ": " + result )
  }
}



task hello { 
    doLast { 
        println 'Hello, World!'
    }
}
task intro(dependsOn: appengineRun) {
    doLast {
        println "I'm Gradle"
    }
}

task datanucleusEnhance {
    description "Enhance JPA model classes using DataNucleus Enhancer"
    dependsOn compileJava

    doLast {    
        // define the entity classes
        def entityFiles = fileTree(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir).matching {
            include 'com/example/april/full/SampleJdoClass.class'
        }
        ant.echo("James was here")
        println "Enhancing with DataNucleus the following files"
        entityFiles.getFiles().each {
            println it
        }

        // define Ant task for DataNucleus Enhancer
        ant.taskdef(
            name : 'datanucleusenhancer',
            classpath : sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
            // classname : 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerTask'
            // the below is for DataNucleus Enhancer 3.1.1
            classname : 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask'
        )

        // run the DataNucleus Enhancer as an Ant task
        /*ant.datanucleusenhancer(
            classpath: sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
            verbose: true) {
            entityFiles.addToAntBuilder(ant, 'fileset', FileCollection.AntType.FileSet)
        }*/

        ant.datanucleusenhancer( dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.canonicalPath.toURI().toString(), verbose: 'true') {
            classpath {
                pathelement(location: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.canonicalPath.toURI().toString())
                //pathelement(path: configurations.jdo.asPath)
                pathelement(path: sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath)
            }
            fileset(dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.canonicalPath.toURI().toString()) {
                include(name: '**/*.class')
            }
        }
    }
}

classes.dependsOn(datanucleusEnhance)

//build.dependsOn appengineRun

group   = "com.example.appenginej8"        // Generated output GroupId
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"       // Version in generated output

sourceCompatibility = 1.8     // App Engine Flexible uses Java 8
targetCompatibility = 1.8     // App Engine Flexible uses Java 8
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are deploying to App Engine flexible with a compat runtime?  App Engine standard Java 8?  Or something else?

Comment: Our official statement is: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2 I'll take a look once I know where you are running.

Comment: My first pass would be to skip ant and try using the [gradle maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) plugin to hook that.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279503/how-can-i-run-datanucleus-enhancer-from-gradle ?

Comment: This is Java 8, Google App Engine Standard environment.  It works with Maven, but we would prefer to get this to work with Gradle...  Tomorrow I'm going to look at the manual java command that Maven and Gradle produce and try to compare all the dependencies to see what is going on...